# Adding a service reference to a breeze odata service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, odata, breeze

Is it possible to consume an OData service (implemented using .Net MVC) with Breeze controllers?

I tried adding a Service Reference from a client aplication, but it simply cannot find a service endpoint when I use Breeze controller on the service.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Googling 'breeze odata' ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on the server you will need to create a WCF DataService, something like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class ODataService : DataService<Your_EF_DbContext> {

  // Add your Entity Set names here ... for example
  config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Customers", EntitySetRights.All);
  config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Orders", EntitySetRights.All);
  config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Employees", EntitySetRights.All);

  // V3 supported in our next release as well.
  config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2; 
  config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
}
```

Then from the Breeze client you will need to call

```
 breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("dataService", "OData");
```

to initialize Breeze's OData handling.  Then you create an EntityManager and connect to your service. Something like this:

```
 var myEntityManager = new breeze.EntityManager("http://localhost:9009/ODataService.svc");
```

You can now query and save from your data service via the EntityManager.